# Coldfusion Connection Code

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, hosting, connection-string

OK, Ive got my site all up - just not working. ahah. I need (I think) the correct code for a connection string to my database etc. I'm using ColdFsuion and Mysql. My code for the connection string is as follows:

```
<CFQUERY 
  NAME="cfGossip" 
  DATASOURCE="mysqlcf_bridgettip" 
  USERNAME="<bridgettip>" 
  PASSWORD="<*******>"
>
</CFQUERY>
```

My DNS on my hosting plan is, well I think is - mysqlcf_bridgettips and on my ColdFusion is cfGossip. I'm not sure which one to use, or if it's even one of them...? It says the error is there when I try access my index.cfm page.

The error over all is :

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be 
displayed.
```

Is it the connection string that is wrong? I would really love any help at all - rewriting my string etc.

Comment: Yer, I got that string from connectionstrings.com! - But it hasn't worked for me yet :( - still having error 500.

Comment: But connectionstrings.com provides connections strings for Windows (VBScript/ADO/ASP/.NET) only, no ColdFusion info there. You don't have to use a connection string anyway in ColdFusion for a garden variety MySQL connection.

Comment: Depending on the version of Coldfusion and MySQL you are using, you may need to install a custom JDBC driver for MySQL. The hosting provider may have already done that for you. When you setup your datasource you would reference the custom driver.

Answer (score 4):

Typically ColdFusion is easier to handle by adding datasources via the ColdFusion Administrator: See [Adding Data Sources for ColdFusion](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/5.0/Installing_and_Configuring_ColdFusion_Server/datasources5.htm).

Comment: I have one in ColdFusion - a MySQL 4/5 - but does that mean I do not have to add any code in my application to connect to my database that i've uploaded to my hosting account? - also the server on my MySQL and ColdFusion id "localhost" should it be that same as my hosting account server:bridgettips.db.5452582.hostedresource.com? I changed them to give it a try - but it came back with an error...

Comment: @Steven: In the ColdFusion Admin, under data sources: Does the data source test succeed (there's a button to test the connection)? If it does, all you have to do in code is mention the configured data source name in `<cfquery>` tags. No username/password required.

Answer (score 2):

if you cant access the coldfusion administrator and have no control panel to add a datasource you need to ask your host to add a datasource for you with a name. A datasource in this context is different from having the database created - its having the database "registered" with the coldfusion administrator so that it can be referenced via a datasource name

once the datasource is created you can hit it by adding the datasource attribute to the cfquery tag: cfquery name="myquery" datasource="mydatasourcename"

Answer (score 0):

> My DNS on my hosting plan is, well I
>   think is - mysqlcf_bridgettips and on
>   my ColdFusion is cfGossip.

The coldFusion Administrator should have a datasource that contains your mysqlcf_bridgettips information (CF datasource name, database name, server IP and port, username/password).  If you've named that datasource cfGossip in the administrator than your cfquery should look like:

```
<cfquery name = "variableNameOfYourQuery (ex. qUsers)" datasource = "cfGossip">
```

I put my username/password in my datasource in the administrator so I don't have it written in  my code.

I believe CF5 was the only version of CF that allowed DSN-less connections that would require a "connection string".